# Dropping duplicates in Apache Spark DataFrame and keep row with value that has not been dropped already?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, duplicates

Let's say I have a DataFrame as the following:

```
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|   1   |   A   |  
|   1   |   B   |   
|   2   |   A   |   
|   2   |   B   |   
|   3   |   B   |  
+-------+-------+
```

I want to be able to find the pairs of where each unique element from *column1* and *column2* fit in 
**exactly** one pair. Therefore, I would hope the outcome would be:

```
+-------+-------+
|column1|column2|
+-------+-------+
|   1   |   A   |   
|   2   |   B   |   
+-------+-------+
```

Notice that the pair (2, A) was removed because A was already paired up with 1. Also 3 was removed because B was already paired up with 2.

Is there a way to do this with Spark?

So far the only solution I came up with is just running a `.collect()` and then `mapping` each row and adding each value of A and B into a set. Therefore, when I meet a row and either an element from column A or B is already in the set, I remove that row.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Would pairs (2,A) and (1,B) be an acceptable result ?

Comment: @baitmbarek yes it would

Comment: A possible solution, although an inefficient one is to iterate over your dataset, filtering at each iteration. Something like: `val rowSequence: mutable.Buffer[Row] = mutable.Buffer()

    while (someDF.count() != 0) {
      val entry: Row = someDF.take(1)(0)
      someDF = someDF.filter(col("column1") =!= lit(entry.get(0).asInstanceOf[Int])
        and col("column2") =!= lit(entry.get(1).asInstanceOf[String])).cache()
      rowSequence.append(entry)
    }` Instead of storing all in a Seq[Row],you can, once in a while. union the results in an output dataframe and clear the rowSequence.